# Почему CheckedItems не содержит одного элемента

Tags: c#, winforms

в winforms использую CheckedListBox, он содержит коллекцию CheckedItems

```
private void BarcodeKeyValuePairsItemCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var items = new List<string>();
            foreach(var item in BarcodeKeyValuePairs.CheckedItems)
                items.Add(item.ToString());
            BarcodeKeyValuePairsItemChecked?.Invoke(items);
        }
```

Когда я кликаю первый раз по check-боксу эта коллекция пустая, хотя как минимум 1 элемент выбран, если выбирать больше, то предыдущий появляется в коллекции, а нового опять нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666682/which-checkedlistbox-event-triggers-after-a-item-is-checked) ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: @PavelPopov, Да, я там уже был, но мне важно сохранить порядок в списке, и не хотелось бы воротить для этого код, меня интересует почему вообще такое неочевидное поведение, и возможно есть альтернативы этому списку.

Comment: ну так, а вы кроме ответа на тот вопрос остальные предложенные варианты смотрели ? там есть много разных решений, но я так понимаю это все костыли т.к. прямого решения нет